# How to implement what I call a "wraparound sort" around an arbitrary value in C++?

Tags: c++, sorting

Given a vector of ints, I would like to implement what I am calling in my mind a "wraparound sort."  Basically, given an arbitrary value, all of the values greater than or equal to that value are listed first in ascending order, and than all values less than the arbitrary value, again in ascending order.  For a value of 12, a wraparound sorted array would look like:

```
[13, 15, 18, 29, 32, 1, 3, 4, 8, 9, 11]
```

What would be a way to implement such a sort?  I am fine assuming as a starting point a vector that is already sorted in ascending order without the wraparound characteristic, since it's easy enough to get to that state, if such an assumption is useful.

Comment: `std::partition` -- start with that.  That would put all elements less than an item on one side of the partition, all elements greater on the other side of the partition.

Comment: `std::sort` + `std::upper_bound` + `std::rotate`

Answer (score 5):

You can do this combining [`std::partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/partition) and [`std::sort`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort).  `std::partition` will split the vector around the partition point and then you can use `std::sort` to sort both halves.  That would look like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector vec = {1,3,4,8,9,11,13,15,18,29,32};
    // all elements >= 12 come first, return value is end iterator of that set
    auto front_end = std::partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto elm){return elm >= 12;});
    // sort first half
    std::sort(vec.begin(), front_end);
    // sort second half
    std::sort(front_end, vec.end());
    for (auto e : vec)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

which outputs

```
13 15 18 29 32 1 3 4 8 9 11
```

---

From [PaulMcKenzie](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3133316/paulmckenzie)'s comment you can reduce the code size a little bit by using [`std::stable_partition`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/stable_partition) on a sorted vector.  That would look like

```
int main()
{
    std::vector vec = {1,3,4,8,9,11,13,15,18,29,32};
    // sort the vector
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());
    // all elements >= 12 come first in the order they had in the sorted vector
    std::stable_partition(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [](auto elm){return elm >= 12;});
    for (auto e : vec)
        std::cout << e << " ";
}
```

It should be noted that `std::stable_partition` does try to do an allocation to be as efficient as `std::partition` and if it can't do that then it falls back to a less efficient O(NlogN) algorithm.

Comment: `std::stable_partition` will automatically sort the items, given that the original input is sorted.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie Good point.  Added to the answer since it makes it even easier.

Comment: Now a good test is to see if sorting the entire range and using `stable_partition` is faster than `std::partition` and calling `std::sort` twice for each subrange.

Comment: My gut says the former will be slightly faster since it should require less function calls.

Comment: `stable_partition` requires an allocation though.

Comment: @T.C. I've added that into the answer since I didn't call that out.

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`lower_bound`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/lower_bound) and [`rotate`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/rotate) on the sorted array:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int pivot = 12;
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,3,4,8,9,11,13,15,18,29,32,12};

    // sort the array
    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end());

    // find the first element >= the pivot
    auto it = std::lower_bound(vec.begin(), vec.end(), pivot);

    // rotate so that it's in the first position
    std::rotate(vec.begin(), it, vec.end());

    for (auto v : vec)
        std::cout << v  << " ";
}
```

---

or you can use [sort](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/algorithm/sort) with a custom comparator:

```
#include <vector>
#include <algorithm>
#include <iostream>

int main()
{
    int pivot = 12;
    std::vector<int> vec = {1,3,4,8,9,11,13,15,18,29,32,12};

    std::sort(vec.begin(), vec.end(), [pivot](int lhs, int rhs) {
        if ((lhs <= pivot && rhs <= pivot) || (lhs > pivot && rhs > pivot)) 
        {
            // on the same side wrt pivot -> true if lhs is smaller than rhs
            return lhs < rhs;
        }
        // either (lhs <= pivot) && (rhs > pivot)
        // or (lhs > pivot) && (rhs <= pivot)
        // -> true if rhs is smaller than lhs
        return rhs < lhs;
    });

    for (auto v : vec)
        std::cout << v  << " ";
}
```